# Обрезать строку в переменной

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, bash

Категорически приветствую!
Существует некий скрипт, в переменной которого содержится строка: `hello-1.my.domain.local hello-world-12.two.domain.local hello-7.three.domain.local hello-world-16.my.domain.local`

Подскажите пожалуйста наиболее рациональный и правильный способ приведения этой строки к виду `hello-1.my,hello-world-12.two,hello-7.three,hello-world-16.my`

Сейчас я делаю это так:

```
VAR2=`echo $VAR1 | sed 's/.domain.local/,/g;s/ //g;s/,$//'`
```

Что на мой взгляд отвратительно (хотя бы из-за хардкода `.domain.local`)

Comment: Почему вам не нравится `.domain.local` в регулярном выражении? Каковы требования к шаблону, что считать разделителем?

Comment: Потому что это хардкод) Исходя из примера - разделитель это точка, оставлять надо два сегмента домена нижнего уровня, остальное обрезать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
sed -E 's/(\.[^.]+){2}([ \t]+|$)/,/g; s/,$//'
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/L41MkN).

Шаблон `(\.[^.]+){2}([ \t]+|$)` находит две последовательности (`(...){2}`) "точка" (`\.`) + "один и более символов, отличных от точки" (`[^.]+`), за которым следует один и более пробелов (`[ \t]+`) или символов табуляции или (`|`) конец строки (`$`), и заменяет на запятую. `s/,$//` необходим для удаления запятой, добавленной в конце строки.

Версия с `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="."; RS=" "; ORS=","} {NF-=2;print}' | sed 's/,$//'
```

И более продвинутая версия без необходимости в `sed`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="."; RS=" "} {NF-=2; l=l $0 ","} END{sub(/,$/, "", l); print l}'
```

См. [онлайн-демо](https://ideone.com/mkQMav).

Кратко:

- `BEGIN {FS=OFS="."; RS=" "}` - `FS=OFS="."` задают разделитель полей (символ `.`) при чтении и записи, а `RS=" "` задаёт разделитель строк (пробел)
- `{NF-=2; l=l $0 ","}` - уменьшаем кол-во полей на 2 для каждой строки и добавляем значение строки к переменной `l` + запятая
- `END{sub(/,$/, "", l); print l}` - в конце удяляем последнюю запятую.

Comment: Отлично, только я б сделал вот так `VAR2=$(sed -E 's/(\.[^.]+){2}([ \t]+|$)/,/g; s/,$//' <<< $s)` , а то ох уж мне эти `echo ...` :)

Comment: Премного благодарен)

Answer (score 1):

Раз стоит [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) добавлю свой вариант тоже:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# file :  var-cut.sh
var_string="hello-1.my.domain.local hello-world-12.two.domain.local hello-7.three.domain.local hello-world-16.my.domain.local"

for split in ${var_string//.domain.local}; do
    echo $split
done | paste -d"," -s -
echo
echo "${var_string//.domain.local/,}"
# end of var-cut.sh
```

вывод

```
~$ ./var-cut.sh
hello-1.my,hello-world-12.two,hello-7.three,hello-world-16.my

hello-1.my, hello-world-12.two, hello-7.three, hello-world-16.my,
```

Comment: @0andriy в метках стоит  `bash`

Comment: @0andriy стоит тег `linux` НЕ стоит  тег `sed` но дан ответ по этому тэгу с оглядкой что ВСЕ *Linux содержат эту утилиту, зачем то стоит тэг `bash` по которому и дал ответ.

Comment: @0andriy у меня именно `bash`. Если для Вас недостаточно какой-то информации в топике - сообщите мне и я по возможности добавлю её. 
Спасибо @Hellseher за свою версию)

Comment: @whoknow, замечательно! Я нашёл теги `sh` и `shell`.